# Moving forward in cardboard using first person controller script

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

How to add first person character controller in google cardboard so that it moves forward in continuous direction?
I know it is stupid question but since I am new and actually made a simple cardboard game just few hours ago.I am not getting how to add first person controller script to my google card board game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a **AutoWalk.cs** script from github that I personally use to make my character walk. This script makes the camera (and the binded character) move forward with a simple head tilt or magnet trigger. 
https://github.com/JuppOtto/Google-Cardboard/blob/master/Autowalk.cs

> NOTE: The code in github is for Google Cardboard SDK. So you will have
>   to modify it a little bit if you want to make it compatible to the
>   latest Google VR SDK (few variable name changes).

This is however a temporary fix that I recommend as we wait for Google to release DayDream

Comment: How can I detect collisions with some objects ?

Comment: You should put that up as question rather than a comment.
In the inspector panel of a gameobject, add a "Collider" Component on that object (Cube, Sphere or Capsule). Set its isTrigger property to true. When any object comes in contact, two functions are called OnTriggerEnter and OnCollision. Choose which function is suitable for you.

Comment: Awesome! THanks I have been looking for this really badly!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just insert the GvrViewerMain.prefab in the scene, this prefab change all your cameras in Stereoscopic rendering, u just need put ur FPSController and modify the 101 line in script FirsPersonController.cs inside him.

Change this line

```
Vector3 desiredMove = transform.forward*m_Input.y + transform.right*m_Input.x;//MODIFIED TO WALK FOR EVER
```

U just need replace m_Input.y by Time.deltaTime, like this.

```
Vector3 desiredMove = transform.forward*Time.deltaTime + transform.right*m_Input.x;//MODIFIED TO WALK FOR EVER
```

more clean solution:

Add a camera in your scene, add a characterController component.;
Add a new script inside the camera:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    void Update() {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```